# Why SessionComponent::write() works on a mate's computer, but not on mine?

Tags: cakephp

Does it have anything to do with PHP or Apache configurations?

Error Message:

`Non-static method SessionComponent::write() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context [APP\View\Households\add.ctp, line 64]`

Line 64:
`SessionComponent::write('ChildCounter', -1);`

Comment: same browsers? Are you developing on localhost? (both of you?)

Comment: We are 3 working in this project. We use localhost and a server. This works on all of them but mine. I figured that because my project was in a subfolder of www of wamp, it didn't work. And also I'm now using  CakeSession::write instead of SessionComponent::write. But for them that thing still work without error message, and when I use it it doesn;t work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SessionComponent::write() should not be called statically
```

So why do you do it? :)

Either use it properly as documented:

```
$this->Session->write()
```

inside the correct scope (controller/component), of course.

or use the static CakeSession access:

```
CakeSession::write()
```

anywhere else in your APP.

Comment: I changed for CakeSession::write(). And it only worked when I moved my cake project folder to work in http://localhost/, before I had http://localhost/myProject, and even with CakeSession::write() it didn't work.

Comment: We tried the following code, and it worked (but shouldn't) for their computers, and as expected it didn't work on mine. What configuration allows them to execute a method that is not static as a static one?
`code`
<?php
class Test{
    public function printSomething( $var ){
        echo $var;
    }
}

Test::printSomething( "HELLO" );
?>
`code`